# How to pass a list/tuple into an environment variable for Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

anybody know how I can pass a list into an environment variable? At the moment I am trying to put a list of codes into my settings.py file.

I have this in my .env file:

```
ALLOWED_CODES='AB01', 'AB02'
```

In my settings.py this is what I have:

```
ALLOWED_CODES = [os.environ.get('ALLOWED_POSTCODES')]
```

If run docker-compose config it is parsed as:

```
ALLOWED_CODES: '''AB01'', ''AB02'''
```

What I want is for it to return the exact list defined in the .env file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`os.environ.get('ALLOWED_POSTCODES')` will always return a string. It's up to you to convert that into a list.

```
ALLOWED_CODES='AB01', 'AB02'
```

If you could change your `.env` file to

```
ALLOWED_CODES=AB01,AB02
```

then you could do

```
ALLOWED_CODES = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_POSTCODES').split(",")
```

You could probably parse the current value into your required list, but the string manipulation would be harder.

You might want to use a package that can handle `.env` files for you, for example [`django-environ`](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.